# Laravel 5.5 add form id

Tags: forms, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravelcollective, laravel-form

I have the following:
`{!! Form::model($houses, ['method' => 'PATCH','route' => ['houses.update', $houses->id]]) !!}`

and  `{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'houses.store','method'=>'POST')) !!}`

witch result in:
`<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/j/public_html/houses/2" accept-charset="UTF-8">`

and  `<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/j/public_html/houses" accept-charset="UTF-8">`

How do I add an `<form id="houseform" ...` in both of them??

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
{!! Form::model($houses, [
           'method' => 'PATCH',
           'route' => ['houses.update', $houses->id], 
           'id' => 'houseform'
   ]) !!}
```

Similar for 2nd:

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'houses.store','method'=>'POST', 'id' => 'houseform')) !!}
```

Comment: Thanks @Marcin , I was wrongly trying something like ```{!! Form::model($houses, ['method' => 'PATCH','route' => ['houses.update', $houses->id]]), 'id' => 'houseform' !!}``` It works now!